# modify ant classpath on the fly

Tags: ant, ivy

I want to use resolvers (ssh) which are dependant on ant classpath.

Something like

```
<resolvers>
...
<ssh ...
...
</resolvers>
```

To use it I need jsch in ant classpath. Ant script should depends only on common lib (which also includes resolved jsch dependencies) - to use it on any client PC. Scenario is:

1. task to download lib.
2. Extract libs (jsch and etc.)
3. ivy:configure

But ivy:configure does not have any classpathref param, so it is unclear for me how to load jars I extracted.

Is it possible?

Or, probably, somehow run ant again internally with extended classpath?

Comment: Ok,

looks I found solution (shame on me - rtfm is good answer sometimes):
ivysettings accept <classpath /> on toplevel with file or url for resolvers.
Unfortunatelly it does not accept refid or building path. I found issue in ivy jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-531 which looks like resolved in some patch bu still open. And refid does not work against ivy-2.2

Comment: You can and should post your solution as an answer to this question(which you can accept later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
so my comment to question looked good for me but at the end it did not work.

The only way I found (working way I mean) is to to run ant script with

1. Download common-lib (with ) which includes all jar-libs required for optional ivy processing
2. Construct new classpath and run exec on same build file with required target:

   ```
   <target name="call.task" if="wrapped.task.name">
   <path id="ant.class.path">
       <fileset dir="${tools.lib.dir}" >
           <include name="*.jar" />
       </fileset>
       <pathelement location="${java.class.path}" />
   </path>

   <condition property="append.dest.dir" value="-Ddest.dir=${dest.dir}" else="">
       <isset property="dest.dir"/>
   </condition>

   <exec executable="ant" failonerror="true">
       <arg line="-f ivy-build.xml" />
       <arg line='-lib "${toString:ant.class.path}"' />
       <arg value="${wrapped.task.name}" />
       <arg value="${append.dest.dir}" />
   </exec>
   </target>
   ```